# Installed Ubuntu using USB stick, now cannot modify files on USB stick

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu

Sorry if this is a really vague question. My issue is when I plug in my flash drive, it shows up as "Kubuntu 20.10 amd64" (I'm assuming it's registering it as this because I installed kubuntu using this flash drive). I have no way to delete these files. Any time I create a partition table, it appears to work, then I create a partition and get an error each time (2nd screenshot). Again, I apologize if this is a basic question but I'm befuddled as to where to go from here, not being linux savvy.

Note: I have looked at a lot of pages, but it's really hard for me to understand anything anybody is saying. I feel like a complete noob when looking at other questions because mine looks extremely basic and like it lacks effort in comparison. I've explained my problem as much as I can, and wish I could further to help anybody figure it out.

What the flash drive looks like in Dolphin:

[image]

The error I get when trying to create a partition (to wipe the data and put new files on it)

[image]

Comment: The installer is on a read-only filesystem, You cannot modify it. You can only use it as-is, or reformat the USB stick.

Comment: Reformatting was the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gparted. That USB stick needs to be formatted.

And don't forget to "umount" that drive before

Comment: Thank you, this was a very simple solution. All I had to do was install gparted, unmount, then format.